# Algorithm for finding a sequence of characters

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that :

1. accepts a string of characters(initial), i.e. a DNA sequence.
   The number of characters that are accepted should be given as an input before inserting the string.
2. Accepts a number, then receives the same number of characters
3. Find all the possible 'mutations' that could occur from input 2, and check in input 1 whether there are occurrences of these mutations.
   Mutations are a number of strings that could be made from input 2. For example, with AGGT, GAGT, GGAT, TGGA, AGGT, ATGG, and AGTG.

So a sample run of the program would be like
2
6 4 
ATGGAT
AGGT

3

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: please show us some effort!

Comment: What is the definition of "mutation"? A "number of strings made from" is a little vague. The example looks like a mutation is simply a reordering of characters, but then why "TAGG" would be a mutation of "AGGT", but isn't according to your example.

Comment: Also, Stackoverflow is a site for learning to code. You are not learning if we simply give you the answer, and we can not explain the answer because we don't know what you already understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when you ask a question on this site, you should show us the effort you put in your work and exactly show or tell us where do you think what you did does not work.

I am not giving you an answer, but I'm giving you better: the opportunity to learn more on the subject. You can learn about what we call in java "regular expressions" here:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

If you make an update of your query showing us what you did, people might be more encline to help you. Stackoverflow has a great community of programmers who are willing to help you just as long as you show them respect by showing where you failed and not directly asking answers for your type of problems !

Learning about regex will definetly help you out to solve this situation. If you build a method using regex and matches and you have issues with it, post what you did and what was intended with this method !

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Wow man! Thank you so much!! It's always better to learn how to fish than to just spoon-feed on other ppl's efforts. I wanted the guidance, and I think you brought me where I want to go.

Comment: Glad to help you out! I've been where you were not long ago haha. Please check my answer as the answer for your query @JWY

Comment: What makes you think regular expressions will be helpful here? I don't think a mutation can be easily expressed in regular expressions - and if all you want is you count occurences of a specific substring, `String.indexOf` is quite a bit simpler and faster ... but well I guess such a bad question does deserve a bad answer.